# How do you change the DVD+R drive's region after the maximum changes have expired in Windows?

Tags: drivers, dvd

In Windows, when you change a DVD+R drive's region, it removes a change from the available changes and when it gets to 0, it stops you from changing the drive's region.  How can you bypass/change this limit?  **Don't say it's impossible.  I know it isn't.**  It's simply not possible that the hardware itself blocks you from changing after the maximum changes.

Comment: It may not be possible; I believe that the limit to region changes may be embedded in the drive hardware.

Comment: Yes it is a firmware restriction stored on the optical drive, do some research on your drive model to see if there is a hack, bet there is.

Comment: Is there a way to override it at a software level (such as a driver reporting a different region)?

Comment: Use a library that bypass the whole region thing, e.g. libdvdcss

Comment: Instead of watching the DVD straight ahead, backup the content to a .mkv file using MakeMkv. This will bypass the region restriction and the next time you can watch the movie without having to insert the DVD. Just be careful, a „backup copy“ for personal use is legal but you mustn’t give a copy to anyone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash it with a hacked firmware. If no firmware for your drive exists yet, reverse-engineer the firmware and hack it yourself. So it is not impossible, it's just extremely challenging.